# Anonymous Function/Closure and using self:: or static::

Tags: php, static, closures, anonymous-function

I am working with anonymous functions where I am creating anonymous function outside of the object, and then adding it to an object later in which it will be used with __callStatic magic function. The closures that are being added to contain methods from the parent class. I am wondering if I would be able to call those methods from the closure?

Right now I get this error:

```
EmptyObject::addMethod('open', function(){
    if (static::_hasAdapter(get_class(), __FUNCTION__))
            return self::_callAdapter(get_class(), __FUNCTION__, $details);

    echo '<p>You have mail!</p>';
});
```

throws this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access static:: when no class scope is active in

And

```
//Add the functions
EmptyObject::addMethod('open', function(){
    if (EmptyObject::_hasAdapter('EmptyObject', __FUNCTION__))
            return EmptyObject::_callAdapter('EmptyObject', __FUNCTION__, $details);

    echo '<p>You have mail!</p>';
});
```

throw this error because the method is protected

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method '_hasAdapter' was not found in class EmptyObject'

Comment: Old php.. In 5.5.9 I can see 'static::' in anonimous function

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve this by using [Closure::bind()](http://au.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) (PHP >= 5.4.0)

```
abstract class EmptyObject
{
   protected static $methods = array();

   final public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
   {
      return call_user_func(self::$methods[$name], $arguments);
   }

   final public static function addMethod($name, $fn)
   {
      self::$methods[$name] = Closure::bind($fn, NULL, __CLASS__);
   }

   final protected static function protectedMethod()
   {
      echo __METHOD__ . " was called" . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Now any anonymous function passed to EmptyObject::addMethod() will be run in the scope of the EmptyObject class

```
EmptyObject::addMethod("test", function()
{
   self::protectedMethod();
});


// will output:
// EmptyObject::protectedMethod was called

EmptyObject::test();
```

Comment: You should omit the `__CLASS__` argument(or set it to `'static'`, e.g. the default) in case of late static binding.

Answer (score 14):

Simply store the class name and pass it to the closure via `use`. You can call any public static method or grab public static properties or constants this way. If the closure is passed off to a different context it will still work as long as the correct value for `$class` was passed to it when it was created. Works for php 5.3:

```
class test {
    public static function callMe() { echo 'call me '; }

    public static function runTest() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        $call = function() use ($class) {
            $class::callMe();   
        };
        $call();
    }
}
test::runTest();
```

Answer (score 3):

[Closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) are called like that for a reason. They 'enclose' the scope they're defined in. They are not simply blocks of code that can pick up the scope from the place they're pasted into.

Comment: Makes sense, but then how would you accomplish the above without making the method public?  In javascript, you would just save a reference to the function in a local variable and call it within the closure.  How do you do this in PHP?

Comment: The way scope works in JavaScript and PHP is very different. Starting from how in PHP external scope is not visible inside functions, ending on how in JavaScript you can change the scope in which function is executed. In other words: PHP is not well suited for metaprogramming like this. Perhaps you could do something with Reflection extension, but I'm not sure about that. Another way would be using eval probably, but that has it's own drawbacks.